# How to Place a Link to a button

Tags: css

I want to override this forms submit button functionality to just open a link instead when its clicked but maintain its css style and the name Book Now. You can see the link silverpalmkilifi.co.ke on the homepage their is an availability search form which i want to keep there but i am not using the same plugin. I wanted to either style the motopress hotel booking plugin availability search to resemble this but my knowledge is not as much so i now just want to change the Book Now button to redirect to the rooms page link.

```html
 <p class="hb-submit">
                <button class="btn btn-solid btn-sm <?php echo esc_attr($btn_color); ?>" type="submit"><?php esc_html_e( 'Book now', 'rokka' ); ?></button>
       </p>
```

Comment: You can change its behaviour using `event.preventDefault()` method and thereby specifying the functionality you are looking for

Comment: Thanks Abin, but i dont know how to do that. Any help

Answer (score 1):

You can try it if you use Bootsrap:

```
<a href="https://my-site.com" class="btn btn-primary">Go to Site</a>
```

If you don't use Bootstrap:

```
<a href="https://my-site.com" class="button">Go to Site</a>
a.button {
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    -moz-appearance: button;
    appearance: button;

    text-decoration: none;
    color: initial;
}
```

Comment: Sarah thanks but i want to maintain my styles could you edit for me this <p class="hb-submit">
            <button class="btn btn-solid btn-sm <?php echo esc_attr($btn_color); ?>" type="submit"><?php esc_html_e( 'Book now', 'rokka' ); ?></button>
   
        </p>

Comment: I think my answer above does what you're looking for: `<p class="hb-submit"><a href="http://www.yourlink.com" class="btn btn-solid btn-sm <?php echo esc_attr($btn_color); ?>"<?php esc_html_e( 'Book now', 'rokka' ); ?></a></p>` – Let us know if it works

Answer (score 1):

You can make an anchor look like a button by styling it as a block level element. It appears like your website is using Bootstrap, so you can probably just apply the same classes to an anchor instead:

```
<p class="hb-submit">
            <a href="http://www.yourlink.com" class="btn btn-solid btn-sm <?php echo esc_attr($btn_color); ?>"<?php esc_html_e( 'Book now', 'rokka' ); ?></a>
   </p>
```

Comment: This has worked interms of clicking and redirecting but it has also distorted some css styles on the site. Could you recraft it maybe.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share an image of the button you're trying to recreate

Comment: Thanks Dave would you mind kindly checking the link silverpalmkilifi.co.ke, its just right on the frontpage on the slider. Please

Comment: I can’t seem to load that website. Could you take a screenshot and add it to your question?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const form = document.getElementById('form');

form.addEventListener('submit', logSubmit);

function logSubmit(event) {
debugger;
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log('Default behaviour stopped');
  // Add the code to redirect to next page here.
}
```

```html
<form id='form'>
  <input type="text" />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Check this snippet.